# block for one iteration of endless loop thread

Tags: .net, thread-safety

I have a thread that is looping and doing some work and sleeping between executions. I need a method that will force the loop to execute one iteration and wait until one full iteration is complete

I am able to force the loop to run with an `AutoResetEvent` but cant think of a safe way to wait until the tread has done a single iteration.

```
public class EndlessLoopThread
{
    private AutoResetEvent _wakeupEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private Thread _thread;
    public int Count;

    public EndlessLoopThread()
    {
        _thread = new Thread((s) =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //... (Do a bunch of important stuff here)
                Interlocked.Increment(ref Count);

                _wakeupEvent.WaitOne(5000);
            }
        });
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void DoStuffOnThreadAndBlockUntilDone()
    {
        _wakeupEvent.Set();

        //how do i block until the thread has done its stuff and gone back to sleep
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can block until the thread does its work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a signaling mechanism from the thread to the method that should wait. And then use the following:

```
_workStarted.Reset();
_workCompleted.Reset();
_wakeupEvent.Set();
_workStarted.WaitOne();
_workCompleted.WaitOne();
```

This should guarantee that important stuff has been executed at least once.

However the solution is somewhat complex which indicates that the problem could be redesigned. I think you could be better of using a consumer/producer like pattern. Adding stuff to be done and waiting for the particular stuff to complete or for there be nothing left to process. More knowledge about the use case is required though.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that will do it. I would like to redesign it, unfortunately this is an existing code base that is complicated, unfamiliar and fragile. Wanted a runonce method to get some unit tests working consistently.